# Problem getting jar file deployed : Error dependencies

Tags: java, maven, amazon-ec2, okhttp

Hi everybody i faced this poblem two times and i'm blocked...
i.e: when i build my jar file and i try to run it in my instance ec2 i faced this problem i have all dependencies with maven but still have this problem...
Any ideas or help please !!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okhttp3/OkHttpClient
            at com.ACList.Foundry2.Connectivity2.App.<init>(App.java:10)
            at com.ACList.Foundry2.Connectivity2.App.main(App.java:30)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okhttp3.OkHttpClient
            at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            ... 2 more
```

Comment: Force Update your maven project. Do mvn clean install

Comment: @Adya i have already test this step still same problem :/

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816171/square-okhttp-okhttpclient-cannot-be-resolved).

Comment: Do you build a jar that includes the dependencies? If you don't use either the assembly plugin or the maven shade plugin, the jar will _not_ include the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution. After changing my build parameters i was able to get the full jar with all dependencies

here's a version of my pom.xml if anyone faced the same problem

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.ACList.Foundry2.Connectivity2.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```